# is this a picture of a plate girder train bridge or a deck truss train bridge?

Tags: rail, bridges

Is this a picture of a plate girder train bridge or a deck truss train bridge?

[image]

Comment: It is a truss bridge. A plate girder is a solid I beam fitted up by plates for flanges and web.

Comment: The part of the bridge to the left of the stone masonry pier in the photo is a steel deck truss rail bridge.  The part of the bridge to the right of the stone masonry pier is a timber/wood girder on timber bents/piers.  A plate girder is usually an I beam where the flanges are either welded/bolted/rivetted to web.  Deep girders and bridge girders tend to be plate girders.  I beams for buildings and lighter loads tend to be one piece of steel and will be what is referred to as a rolled section as passing the hot steel through a series of rollers forms the standard section size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a truss bridge.

A quick Google Image search will make the difference between the bridge types clear.

This is a [plate girder bridge](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=plate+girder+train+bridge&tbm=isch):

[image]

And this is a [truss bridge](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=deck+truss+train+bridge&tbm=isch):

[image]

Basically, a girder bridge uses a few massive longitudinal beams while a truss instead uses a criss-cross of smaller beams instead.